# Ошибка при удаления данных из субпартиции таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Что не так в синтаксисе удаления данных из субпартиции таблицы

```
truncate table xxx with subpartition (P_201709);
```

Ошибка:

```
ORA-03291: Неверное усечение опции - отсутствует ключевое слово STORAGE
03291. 00000 -  "Invalid truncate option - missing STORAGE keyword"

truncate table xxx with subpartition (P_201709) reuse storage;
```

Так синтаксис тоже неверный. Можете привести пример полного выражения?

Comment: так добавьте ключевое слово (в ошибке же об этом говорится) - используйте `DROP STORAGE` (место освободится и это пространство может использоваться и другими обьектами БД) или `REUSE STORAGE` (пространство экстентов остаётся за таблицей)

Comment: Спасибо, я понимаю, что дело в storage. Но синтакис не подходит )) Добавил в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так выглядит корректный синтаксис:

```
ALTER TABLE xxx
   TRUNCATE SUBPARTITION P_201709
      DROP STORAGE;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE xxx TRUNCATE SUBPARTITION P_201709 DROP STORAGE;
```

[Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-E4E0CACE-67CD-4C75-8B9D-0C16D858863D.htm)